# How to increment & decrement a json value from local storage using angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, local-storage, ng-storage

How to Increment and decrement a json value from local storage using angular.js

I use ngstorage module from angularjs .

my **[Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/cfPbG5/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `item` object while calling `increment`  & `decrement`  function

**Markup**

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in data">
    <span>
        id:{{ item.id }} 
      <button ng-click="increment(item);">+</button>
      age:{{ item.age }}
      <button ng-click="decrement(item);">-</button>                        
      <button data-ng-click="delItem(item)">X</button>
    </span>
</li>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.increment = function (item) {
    if (item.age >= max) { return; }
    item.age++;
};
$scope.decrement = function (item) {
    if (item.age <= min) { return; }
    item.age--;
};
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/uC6Ieq3aRWvH1rb2e4jv?p=preview)

Comment: can you solve this ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689822/how-to-push-all-values-from-the-txt-file-to-local-storage-using-angular-js