# how to push all values from the txt file to local storage using angular js

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I have a sample application which can store values into local storage when user clicks to local button but i want to all values from the txt file to be in local storage  "note2": [] .

[Plunker Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/brbqCm/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And yes i found a way to do so .,

you can use `ng-init='Function name'`

here i use a function when a user click the to local button to push a value to local

```
$scope.cloneItem = function (todo) {
        $scope.$storage.notes.push({
            "price": todo.price,
            "id": todo.id,
            "quan": todo.quan
        });
    }
```

but i want to store all the values from the txt file to local so i use

```
ng-init='your js function name'
```

this function to call push function so that for every ng-repeat the value would push to local

Example :

```
<tr ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-init='cloneItem(todo)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

To put your data in localStorage in angularJS you can use the library [angular-localForage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage).

Example:

```
angular.module('yourModule', ['LocalForageModule'])
.controller('yourCtrl', ['$scope', '$localForage',
    function($scope,$localForage) {
      $localForage.setItem('myName','Olivier Combe').then(function() {
        $localForage.getItem('myName').then(function(data) {
          var myName = data;
        });
      });
 }]);
```

Comment: @Popovokov57 I already done that but can"t able to figure how to store bulk values to localstorage

Comment: @Popovokov57 it"s fine wheather a json or txt file we angularjs can populate them

Comment: @Popovokov57 Found a way to do .. thank you for your response