# Plus minus with single textbox in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two buttons and one text box I want, quantities to be increamented by 1 on click of +plus button and decremented by 1 on click of -minus button. But when it reaches to less than 0 or say 0 the decrement button should be disabled. I have this code here 
[PLunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3KzAt77yfCgwIaoDMaxh?p=preview)

My html code

```
<form id='myform' >
 <button ng-click="increment()"  class='qtyminus'>-</button>
    <input ng-modal="item.qty" type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <button ng-click="decrement()" >+</button>
</form>
```

My js code

```
 $scope.increment = function () {
        alert('hi');
        $scope.item.qty++;
    };
    $scope.decrement = function () {
           $scope.item.qty--;
    };
```

Comment: are you sure that you've provided the right code in Plunker? When I click "+" for incrementing I get a "Bad request" error. And If I press "-" it alerts hi and throws the same error after that. However your question should be solved with the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505010/how-to-increment-decrement-a-json-value-from-local-storage-using-angular-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `ng-diabled` directive
- Correct ty typo @ `ng-modal`, it is **`ng-model`**

*Note:* Consider `<=0` condition as user may enter `<0` value in `input-element`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.qty = 10;
  $scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.qty++;
  };
  $scope.decrement = function() {
    $scope.qty--;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form id='myform' ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="decrement()" class='qtyminus' ng-disabled="qty<=0">-</button>
  <input ng-model="qty" type='text' name='quantity' class='qty' />
  <button ng-click="increment()">+</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey hi can you just modify the code again? I have 2 such plus and minus with text box, its inside ng-repeat.

Comment: Please provide me an directive if possible that should work for any number of products. can you make it please?

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere – I do not find any relation among your `ng-repeat` array and `input-element`

Comment: Yes you can take any variable its just to increase and descrease qty, so I have scope,orders.qty and scope,orders.code so you can use $scope.order,qty, I added ng-repeat just to show you that I am using $index to make it different

Comment: Boss I am not asking free if you feel so please let it be, but thank you, you are a gem I just saw your profile. Mumbaikar ha??? great asach chalu raha sarvana madat karat. :-) bye see you.

Comment: No sir I am new to ng so I thaught a directive would make it work. +1 for you.

Comment: There has to be some relation among your `array` and `input`

Comment: You mean products array and input qty ? no I just want plus minus to work for all ng-repeat items, hence I will be getting ng-model as postfixed with $index

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere – How will you get initial value for input ? Don't you want to have a value of `input` part of _repeated_ object ?

Comment: I just made something like this $scope.orders.qty.push('0'); while getting products from list to display

Comment: I dont know how to use that, I think I am not able to explain my problem well, let it be thanks for you help. I am trying it if I get I will post here.

Comment: I did this using http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/buttons-minus-and-plus-in-input jquery rocks hehehe :-) see you.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code. This should solve your problem

```
<form id='myform' >
 <button ng-click="increment()"  class='qtyminus'>-</button>
    <input ng-model="item.qty" type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <button ng-click="decrement()" ng-disabled="item.qty <= 0">+</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you tell me what if I have the same plus minus button for 10 products inside ng-repeat?

Comment: Please check this one http://plnkr.co/edit/QOydD9lsbOzWKhAk6TH9?p=preview

Comment: Sorry I don't have any experience any directives. So cannot help you on that.